# Swift pass error caught inside function

Tags: swift

There is a function throws custom error.

```
enum MyError: Error {
    case someError(reason: String)
}

func someMethod() throws {
    throw someError(reason: "This is test")
}
```

This method `someMethod()` is called in another method. I want to handle error outside this method.

```
func anotherMethod() throws {
    do {
        try someMethod()
    } catch MyError.someError(let reason) {
        throw MyError.someError(reason: reason) // This should be handled outside this method.
    }
}
```

I want to write it like this but this cannot be compiled.

```
catch let error as MyError.someError {
    throw error
}
```

Is there any better way to throw same error again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write

```
func anotherMethod() throws {
    try someMethod()
}
```

then the error will be handed over.

Comment: That's what i was looking for! Thanks